# Creating UIViews depending on parent views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uinavigationbar

Here is my problem:

I have a 3 views connected to a `UIViewController` 'A'. This view controller 'A' is a child of a `UIPageViewController`. I am looking to arrange the views. However, I am having trouble doing this without hard coding. I am currently using the superview's frame to position the subviews. I have tried using bounds also. But this is all proving to be difficult.

Another issue I cannot workaround is the space taken up by the `UINavigationBar`. Since the view controller only resizes AFTER the `viewDidLoad` method, I don't know when to resize my subviews since the super view is only being resized after the `viewDidLoad` method.

My question is basically: Will hardcoding the frame affect how it looks on iPhone 4, iPhone 5 and iPad? And if yes, then how do I get around the problem of the `ParentViewController` resizing after the `viewDidLoad` method? Should I create subviews in the `viewWillAppear` method? But this seems like bad practice as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using constraints? (Constraints to the rescue...!)

Comment: i was going to say constraints like above user but are these all programmed views? I'm also a little confused on the issue, if you do want resizing their are tons of options like getting the size of the screen of the device that is running the app.

Comment: Yes these are programmed views. I am using `NSLog` to log the frame information. But the actual views are not conforming to the what the Log says. The issue I am having is how to alter views in relation to the superview.

Comment: you have to show all that 3 subViews at the sametime on Viewcontroller? or at different time or after some event occurs?